# How to add self-signed certificate to Java truststore?

Tags: java, jpackage

I am trying jpackage Java 14 to package my Spring application,
I have requirement to self-sign certificate Java trust store, but I cannot find the keytool in the jpackage image.

How can I add a self-signed certificate to the Java truststore in Java 14 jpackage?

Comment: I would recommend you Google this. You'll find many tutorials that can explain better than we can here.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer:

1. Run jlink command to create JRE

```
jdk-14.0.1/bin/jlink --add-modules java.sql,java.naming,java.base,java.logging,java.desktop,java.management,java.security.jgss,java.instrument --output myJRE
```

2. Run jpackage to create image

```
jdk-14.0.1/bin/jpackage --type app-image --runtime-image myJRE --input target/ --name xxx-xxx-app --main-jar xxx-0.0.1.jar  --java-options '-Dspring.config.location=/app/conf/application.properties'
```